# How to migrate a whole partition?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, partition, samba, suse

I have two computers (old and new) connecting by a cable, now I try to move/copy/clone a partition to the new computer, without copying files one by one. Then the new can access the files copied from the old easily, how to do for this question?

Comment: What's the unclear is, I have got some answers.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to clone partition is to attach old harddisk to the new machine and do the cloning. But (depend of files) copy files in most of the cases will be faster

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like clonezilla would be the easiest way to go, if I understand your question correctly and the connection between the computers is working. Also, you could try mount the new partition/s then use rsync to copy everything. I used

```
rsync -avhPHAXx / /path/to/new/root
```

several times recently and it works every time. DO NOT FORGET TO (arch-)chroot into the new partition and install+update grub/your chosen bootloader, or you'll get an os not found type error.

Comment: The problem is I'm a beginner, after connecting computers, how to set them up to access eachother? Should the both computers running Clonezilla for this setup?

Comment: If you can remove the disk from the new and put it in the old you should be able to (easiness dependent on distro and desktop environment) see the new disk, use gparted to partition, then use the rsync command.
If you use Clonezilla you'll have to follow a tutorial as the steps are a little more involved. Honestly in your case the rsync option is way way way easier.

Also - who moderates the moderators? When the mods put a straightforward question on hold it makes you think why...